# Give the initial value ordinary differential equation that $y(t)$ solves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $x^{\prime}(t)=F(x(t), t) ;$ $ x\left(t_{0}\right)=x_{0} .$ Give the
>   IV ODE that $y(t)=x\left(t+t_{0}\right)$ solves.

I am not sure how to approach this mainly because I am not sure exactly what it is that this problem is asking.

Comment: Looks to me like you’re being asked to come up with an ODE for $y$ in terms of $x$ and $F$.

Comment: @amd I do see that. Any chance you could give a hint as to how to start?

Comment: Have you tried differentiating $y(t)$?

Comment: $y'(t)=x'(t+t_0)$ and also $y(0) = x(t_0)=x_0 $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that

$$x^{\prime}(t)=F(x(t), t) , ~~x\left(t_{0}\right)=x_{0}\tag{1}$$

and you have found that

$$y'(t)=x'(t+t_0),~~y(0)=x(t_0)=x_0\tag{2}$$

therefore by $(1)$

$$y'(t)=x'(t+t_0)=F\big(x(t+t_0),t+t_0\big)$$

Comment: I didn't think it would be this trivial. Sometimes it seems like the hardest problems are the trivial ones

Answer (score 0):

The problem is asking for an IVP, that is, an ordinary differential equation of the given form, with an initial condition of the given form, whose solution is a translate of the solution to the given equation. In other words, they want you to perform $t\mapsto t+t_0.$